# Spring mvc 3 - HTTPS access

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I force a page to be accessed via HTTPS only. Need to do this via Spring MVC 3 configuration file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring-security has such a configuration. [see here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel) for how to do it. In short - you force the channel to use https:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" 
        requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" 
        requires-channel="any"/>
</http>
```

If you don't want to use spring-security, here's an interceptor that I wrote:

```
@Component
public class SslInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    // no need to inject it for now..
    private PathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    @Value("${base.url.secure}")
    private String secureRoot;

    @Resource(name="secureLocations")
    private List<String> secureLocations;

    @Value("${use.ssl}")
    private boolean useSsl;


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (useSsl && !request.isSecure() && shouldForceSecure(request.getRequestURI())) {

            String redirectUrl = secureRoot + request.getRequestURI();
            if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
                redirectUrl += "?" + request.getQueryString();
            }
            // force session creation - thus it will be accessible to both the
            // secure and the insecure contexts
            request.getSession(true);
            response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean shouldForceSecure(String path) {
        for (String pattern : secureLocations) {
            if (pathMatcher.match(pattern, path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bozho. The example looks great. Can you also please share with me how this can be done using spring-security configuration.

Comment: Exactly what I want. Infact I did see this article before I posted the question. I am new to Spring MVC. I put in the the spring config file but I was getting parse errors. I know I am asking too much but can you give me a sample XML file? Thank you Bozho.

Comment: @Viren Pushpanayagam that's another question. Try reading the whole documentation and it will become clear how to configure spring-security. I did so a few weeks ago and it worked right away

Answer (score 2):

For an annotation based approach without spring security I wrote an interceptor and a new annotation:

```
/**
 * Request mapping annotation to enforce secure or insecure requests.
 * Per default the annotated mapping is enforced to be secure.
 *
 * @see org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
 */
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Mapping
public @interface RequestProtocol {

  boolean secure() default true;
}
```

So you can simply declare a (here for REST) controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secret", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestProtocol(secure = true)
@ResponseBody
public Result doSecure(@Valid Model model) {
  return doSomething(model));
}
```

To enable the mapping use an interceptor redirecting on the wrong protocol. You could also do a more simple handling by just sending a FORBIDDEN response.

```
/**
 * Interceptor to send a redirect on security enforced mappings with wrong type of request.
 *
 * @see RequestProtocol
 */
class RequestProtocolInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  private static final int PORT_DIFF = 443 - 80;

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
    Boolean secure = checkSecure(handler);
    if (secure != null && request.isSecure() != secure) {
      response.sendRedirect(switchSecure(secure, request.getRequestURL()));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private Boolean checkSecure(Object handler) {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
      HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod)handler;
      RequestProtocol annotation = method.getMethodAnnotation(RequestProtocol.class);
      if (annotation == null) {
        annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method.getBeanType(), RequestProtocol.class);
      }
      return annotation == null ? null : annotation.secure();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private String switchSecure(boolean secure, StringBuffer url) {
    int endSchema = url.indexOf("://");
    url.replace(0, endSchema, secure ? "https" : "http");
    int startPort = url.indexOf(":", endSchema + 3);
    if (startPort != -1) {
      int endPort = url.indexOf("/", startPort);
      int port = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(startPort + 1, endPort));
      port += secure ? PORT_DIFF : -PORT_DIFF;
      url.replace(startPort + 1, endPort, String.valueOf(port));
    }
    return url.toString();
  }
}
```

To enable the interceptor on a pure annotation based Spring config, use the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new RequestProtocolInterceptor());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your Tomcat config.

try adding redirectPort="" in server.xml to the HTTP connector.

Hope it helps.

Update:

This article will explain you how to deal with SSL and has a lot of an examples.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Agree, but every application server has such options even IIS :). I just wrote the idea what should be done.

Comment: Please can you provide an example

Comment: Thanks @Danny but I want to know how I can do it in Spring MVC 3